# any option to show my answer above upvoted answers?

Tags: support, answers, up-votes, sorting, visibility

I have answered a question. I would be the 25th to give the answer. My answer is shown at the last in the list. I am sure that my answer is correct and will solve the questioner's problem. How can my answer be shown on the top or near by so that others give a glance.

Comment: What do you mean? Like paying for a "featured answer"? Last I checked, we're not Facebook. You can't pay to have your content raised above other content.

Comment: [latest answers are shown on top](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tTAXR.png "example") for users who configured [meta-tag:sorting] like me. Not to mention that new answers [meta-tag:bump] the question, giving it extra visibility. Looks like [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 8):

Time.

If your answer is indeed *better* and more correct than the others (and you should really think carefully before adding yet another answer when there are 24 others there already), it will get upvoted and over time will move up in the list.

Comment: FWIW latest answer goes on top of the list immediately for [readers who use "active" sort order](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tTAXR.png "example")